# Monitoring the other Apps from one app in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to create and App that will run in the background and will monitor the user's behavior in term of applications installed, opened and deleted.

i.e Application will save the information in the database that at what time user has installed/opened/deleted an application in iphone.

I wonder if its possible and Apple will allow this??

I tried to google on it but did not get anything, i know if its possible then it would be possible by multiasking only??

Can any one please help me on the same.

Brn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS apps are sandboxed. I wouldn't say impossible but certainly not allowed. You'd have to find a security hole to give you root access first. Oh, and notify us when you do ;).

**Edit:** 
Maybe it wasn't clear in my post but I was at least half joking. Not sure why you want to do what you want to do. I can imagine the following scenarios:

1) Your company wants to monitor everything their users do on their phones. In that case I would either 
a) lock them down and only allow app installation through a company portal (enterprise distribution is possible in iOS) OR

b) forget about iOS alltogether. Blackberry would probably be closer to what you want, although I don't really have experience with that platform. Also, its future is not sure.

2) You're trying to do something illegitimate. Because of iOS's locked down nature it won't be easy. See how few successful attacks there have been in the last years - and that's for a highly successful platform where an attack could be high paying both in terms of money and reputation.

Comment: yeah, seems to be very sophisticated thing, didn't get any solution yet, will share for sure if find some thing:)

Comment: yes Michel, trying this thing is to do something illegitimate and it wont be so easy & even wont be acceptable by Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. Your app can only run when the user chooses to (except for a limited sub-set of tasks like VoIP, etc).

Your app can know nothing about other apps.